# Proper application shutdown before windows xp auto shutdown

Tags: windows-xp, shutdown

I frequently leave the computer on playing a movie or downloading a file while I go to bed. I do use the 'shutdown computer when finished' feature of KMPlayer or getright or uTorrent or whatever program I am using. This method effectively shuts down the computer, but the problem is that there are some applications that seem to exit forcefully when doing this kind of shutdown, this being clearly reflected in winamp not saving the current playlist and config, messenger not saving the chat logs, etc.

My goal here would be to have automatically close properly all applications when the auto/scheduled program triggers it. I am looking for some Windows shutdown mode/setting that does application closing like the user would do.

I am not expecting to auto-click on save dialogs prompts, if this is needed I will do it before leaving the computer on for auto shutdown.

Comment: I think it is more of a problem with the program being coded to shut down gracefully when requested to do so by the OS, more than it is a Windows shutdown problem, not sure there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try `taskkill.exe /IM`, use `tasklist.exe` to see list of processes.

Comment: What does the /IM do?

Comment: Image name, in other words, something like notepad.exe

Answer (score 0):

With [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html) (copy the file to `C:\Windows\System32`) you can set the computer to shut down (softly) by running

```
NirCmd.exe initshutdown <timeinseconds>
```

or if your program supports running a command when it's done,

```
NirCmd.exe initshutdown
```

Comment: That does not solve the OP's problem. Besides, there's already a command for that (>shutdown -s -t <timeinseconds>), no need for a third party app.

Comment: It should, if the app works as described  in the documentation, shut down the computer nonforcefully (if that's word).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, nircmd seems like a nice utility but I doubt this would be any different from timed shutdown

Answer (score 0):

As rightly said by Moab in a comment :

> I think it is more of a problem with
>   the program being coded to shut down
>   gracefully when requested to do so by
>   the OS, more than it is a Windows
>   shutdown problem, not sure there is a
>   solution.

You would need to raise this issue with the Support of winamp and messenger or any other application this happens with. There is no general solution.

Comment: I was hoping there could be different shutdown signals for the OS to send to applications and maybe my windows installation was configured to send a 'inmediate termination' signal or something that could be changed to a 'shutdown please' signal..

Comment: This is already the way shutdown is done in Windows. Forced termination only happens if the program ignores the polite message and for a certain time.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, the thing is we are talking about what I would consider mature applications (nullsoft winamp, windows live messenger) that should be able to handle shutdown signals properly. Also I was not expecting to address this issue separately for each application...

Comment: This might be a problem of a misbehaved plugin, as suggested for example in [this thread](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=267420).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that issue. However I don't think I am using any special plugin for winamp, just the ones that come with the default installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play with the following values in the registry:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WaitToKillAppTimeout 
>   HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop\WaitToKillAppTimeout
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\WaitToKillServiceTimeout

Try increasing the values to allow more time for applications to shut down correctly. But as several users have already noted correctly - often the problem is within the Application, not within Windows shutdown sequence.